# Create and activate Conda environment in same script

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to write an installer that uses both `conda` and `pip`. I'd like to activate the `conda` environment to call `pip`, but doing this in the same script causes problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

conda create -y --name myenv python=3.6
conda init bash
conda activate myenv
# Perform pip-based installation here.
```

Running `bash setup-environment.sh` fails at the `conda activate` step:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

While it's helpful to know that restarting my shell will solve the problem, I can't do that within the script. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running bash in login mode should work, e.g.,

```
bash -l setup-environment.sh
```

Note, the `conda init` in the script is superfluous - it edits the `.bash_profile` but doesn't actually initialize a current bash session; it only needs to be executed once for a user. Hence, the script should be changed to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
set -euo pipefail

conda create -y --name myenv python=3.6 pip
conda activate myenv
# Perform pip-based installation here.
```

and you could just run it like `./setup-environment.sh`.

---

### Alternate Solution: Use YAML Environment Definition

Admittedly, I am missing the other parts you might have planned in your script, but everything that is shown could be more succinctly done using [a Conda YAML environment definition](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually). For example, if you write a YAML file like:

**myenv.yaml**

```
name: myenv
channels:
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3.6
 - pip
 - pip:
   - some_pkg
```

and then run

```
conda env create -f myenv.yaml
```

it would do exactly what your script is doing, including all the pip installations. All commands that you can run in a pip `requirements.txt` can be included in a YAML. See [the Advanced Pip Example](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/master/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip) in the Conda GitHub.